# Pandas Merge() : Merging Datasets with Null Values, better approach

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am new to Machine Learning and I was wondering which is better approach to merge 2 Datasets with NaN values in Python Pandas

Approach 1: remove the NaN values from each Dataset and then Merge them.

Approach 2: Merge the Datasets and then remove the NaN values from Merged Dataset.

Thank you.

Comment: I think both are same thing.

Comment: As a part follow in EDA you can clean and preprocess the data first then apply feature engineering

Comment: They should be the same thing if you mean by merging that you will concatenate the rows nothing more.

Comment: If you eventually will delete the NaN values, I would delete them first. This will make the process afterwards faster

Comment: Thank you everyone for your insights , yes they both came to be same.